# Operate on a list in a pythonic way when output depends on other elements

Tags: python

I have a task requiring an operation on every element of a list, with the outcome of the operation depending on other elements in the list.

For example, I might like to concatenate a list of strings conditional on them starting with a particular character:

This code solves the problem:

```
x = ['*a', 'b', 'c', '*d', 'e', '*f', '*g']
concat = []
for element in x:
    if element.startswith('*'):
        concat.append(element)
    else:
        concat[len(concat) - 1] += element
```

resulting in:

```
concat
Out[16]: ['*abc', '*de', '*f', '*g']
```

But this seems horribly un-Pythonic. How should one operate on the elements of a `list` when the outcome of the operation depends on previous outcomes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A few relevant excerpts from `import this` (the arbiter of what is Pythonic):

- Simple is better than complex
- Readability counts
- Explicit is better than implicit.

I would just use code like this, and not worry about replacing the for loop with something "flatter".

```
x = ['*a', 'b', 'c', '*d', 'e', '*f', '*g']
partials = []
for element in x:
    if element.startswith('*'):
        partials.append([])
    partials[-1].append(element)
concat = map("".join, partials)
```

Comment: Lovely. +1 for bringing the discussion back to "*pythonic*" and away from neat/compact/fast.

Comment: Added your answer to my small benchmark, if you're interested :)

Comment: My slow time on a large input doesn't surprise me :) However, if `x` were really that large, I'd look into building `concat` as I build `x`, rather than waiting until `x` is complete to start.

Comment: @chepner That makes sense. I just figured I'd add it for fun. +1 for addressing the main question of the OP.

Comment: Nitpicking: you should change the last line to a list-comprehension if you want the code to be equivalent to OP's in both python2 and python3.

Comment: I like to use `map` when I think it's more readable and not significantly slower than a list comprehension, but portability between Python 2 and Python 3 is a good reason to choose the list comprehension as well.

Comment: Thanks for your excerpt from the zen of python, but do you really think this complex loop and the implicit algorithm are better for readability? Especially that extra `partials` array seems worse than the OP's code to me.

Comment: @bergi I split the problem into two parts: partitioning the list into a list of lists (the `for` loop), and processing each partition into the desired form (the `map`). You can cleanly split the loop's processing into two parts: first, ensure that the last list in `partials` is appropriate for the current list items, and second, unconditionally place the current item in the last lists. The logic for how the list is partitioned is completely contained in the `if` statement. The OP stated the string-joining problem was just an example; this code can be easily modified for similar problems.

Answer (score 7):

You could use regex to accomplish this succinctly. This does however, sort of circumvent your question regarding how to operate on dependent list elements. Credits to [mbomb007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2415524/mbomb007) for improving the allowed character functionality.

```
import re
z = re.findall('\*[^*]+',"".join(x))
```

**Outputs:**

```
['*abc', '*de', '*f', '*g']
```

---

**Small benchmarking:**

[Donkey Kong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29903458/4686625):

```
import timeit
setup = '''
import re
x = ['*a', 'b', 'c', '*d', 'e', '*f', '*g']
y = ['*a', 'b', 'c', '*d', 'e', '*f', '*g'] * 100
'''
print (min(timeit.Timer('re.findall("\*[^\*]+","".join(x))', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
print (min(timeit.Timer('re.findall("\*[^\*]+","".join(y))', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
```

Returns `0.00226416693456`, and `0.06827958075`, respectively.

[Chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29903809/4686625):

```
setup = '''
x = ['*a', 'b', 'c', '*d', 'e', '*f', '*g']
y = ['*a', 'b', 'c', '*d', 'e', '*f', '*g'] * 100
def chepner(x):
    partials = []
    for element in x:
        if element.startswith('*'):
            partials.append([])
        partials[-1].append(element)
    concat = map("".join, partials)  
    return concat
'''
print (min(timeit.Timer('chepner(x)', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
print (min(timeit.Timer('chepner(y)', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
```

Returns `0.00456210269896` and `0.364635824689`, respectively.

[Saksham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29904042/4686625)

```
setup = '''
x = ['*a', 'b', 'c', '*d', 'e', '*f', '*g'] 
y = ['*a', 'b', 'c', '*d', 'e', '*f', '*g'] * 100

'''
print (min(timeit.Timer("['*'+item for item in ''.join(x).split('*') if item]", setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
print (min(timeit.Timer("['*'+item for item in ''.join(y).split('*') if item]", setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000))))
```

Returns `0.00104848906006`, and `0.0556093171512` respectively.

**tl;dr** Saksham's is slightly faster than mine, then Chepner's follows both of ours.

Comment: Just a note: the ``\`` before the second asterisk is optional since it is contained within a character class. You don't need to edit it, though, if you don't want to.

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```
>>> x = ['*a', 'b', 'c', '*d', 'e', '*f', '*g']
>>> print ['*'+item for item in ''.join(x).split('*') if item]
['*abc', '*de', '*f', '*g']
```

Comment: This is the best answer, in my opinion. +1

Comment: heh its almost the same as my answer :P he just is fixing the output but yeah +1 good answer imho :)

Answer (score 4):

```
"".join(x).split("*")
```

maybe sufficient, of coarse this may be a contrived example in your OP that is oversimplified and as such this will not work

Comment: Agreed that this looks great in this specific (but somewhat fictitious) example. (Although it doesn't *quite* reproduce the output. The stars in the OP are retained.) Is there something more generic to be learned about Pythonic coding through this example though?

Comment: that there is more than one way to skin a cat perhaps? if there was a less fictitious example Im sure we could come up with something equally legible...

Comment: Building off of this, how about `list(map(lambda v: '*' + v, "".join(x).split('*')[1:]))`?

Comment: no ... that goes backwards ... if you really needed it `["*"+x for x in new_list]`

Comment: incredible ... someone really gave me -1 for not having the "*" ?

Comment: It wasn't me, but you didn't accomplish what the OP wanted with your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I feel that this is very Pythonic:

```
# assumes no empty strings, or no spaces in strings
"".join(x).replace('*', ' *').split()
```

---

Here's a functional approach to it:

```
from functools import reduce

# assumes no empty strings
def reduction(l, it):
    if it[0] == '*':
        return l + [it]
    else:
        new_l, last = l[:-1], l[-1]
        return new_l + [last + it]

x = ['*a', 'b', 'c', '*d', 'e', '*f', '*g']

print reduce(reduction, x, [])
>>> ['*abc', '*de', '*f', '*g']
```

If you are a fan of lambdas (not very Pythonic), you could get away with this:

```
# Don't do this, it's ugly and unreadable.
reduce(lambda l, it: l + [it] if it.startswith('*') else l[:-1] + [l[-1]+it], x, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is awfully close to what [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) does, and in fact with a little helping of curry I can make it keep grouping until a "break" condition occurs, such as `startswith('*')`.

```
from itertools import groupby

def new_group_when_true(pred):
    group_num = 0
    def group_for_elem(elem):
        nonlocal group_num
        if pred(elem):
            group_num +=1
        return group_num
    return group_for_elem

l = ['*a', 'b', 'c', '*d', 'e', '*f', '*g']

test = new_group_when_true(lambda elem: elem.startswith('*'))

grouped = [list(v) for k,v in groupby(l, test)]
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> print(grouped)
[['*a', 'b', 'c'], ['*d', 'e'], ['*f'], ['*g']]
```

The `nonlocal` keyword requires Python 3, of course. Another possibility would be to make a class, along the lines of the `groupby` "equivalent code" from the itertools docs.

I don't know that this is more Pythonic than your code, but I think the idea of going to the standard library to see if something *almost* fits your needs is a useful point.